# Google App Engine goapp "deploy" works but "serve" fails, what's going on?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I started using Google App Engine today, so hopefully the answer will be obvious to someone with experience. After simply following [this method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql) to get App Engine interfacing with Cloud SQL, I'm having a frustrating issue: **goapp deploy** succeeds but **goapp serve** fails (using the cloud shell).

Here's the error:

```
XXXX@cloudshell:~/src/XXXX/app-engine (XXXX)$ goapp serve app.yaml
INFO     2018-06-21 07:29:08,115 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2018-06-21 07:29:08,235 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://0.0.0.0:60628
INFO     2018-06-21 07:29:08,305 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2018-06-21 07:29:08,306 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://0.0.0.0:8000
ERROR    2018-06-21 07:29:12,254 go_runtime.py:181] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /google/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /home/XXX/app-engine -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /google/go_appengine/goroot -gopath /home/XXX/gopath:/google/gopath -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_re
build -unsafe -binary_name _go_app -extra_imports appengine_internal/init -work_dir /tmp/tmpT1RTRMappengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/google/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine -l
dflags -L,/google/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine hello.go)
/home/XXX/gopath/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/connection.go:12: can't find import: "context"
2018/06/21 07:29:09 Can't find package "context" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "context" in any of:
    /google/go_appengine/goroot/src/context (from $GOROOT)
    /home/XXX/gopath/src/context (from $GOPATH)
    /google/gopath/src/context
2018/06/21 07:29:12 go-app-builder: build timing: 0×skip (3ms total), 9×compile (2.731s total), 0×link (0 total)
2018/06/21 07:29:12 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 2
```

I'm suspicious that the version of go being used is wrong. The stated version is 1.6.3 but as I understand "context" requires 1.7. Here's the relevant cloud shell output for that:

```
XXXX@cloudshell:~ (XXX)$ goapp version
go version go1.6.3 (appengine-1.9.48) linux/amd64
XXXX@cloudshell:~ (XXX)$ go version
go version go1.10 linux/amd64
```

However, despite my best efforts I have been unable to find any resources on how to manipulate the "goapp" go version.

My app.yaml includes:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.8
```

And **goapp get** yields this:

```
XXXX@cloudshell:~/src/XXX/app-engine (XXX)$ goapp get
package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

The go file itself is an exact copy of the demo from the linked above.

Comment: What happens when you use [`dev_appserver.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server) instead of `goapp serve`? The docs seem to suggest `dev_appserver.py` gives you better control, just like for deploying, where the recommended method is [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/uploadinganapp#deploying_an_app) instead of `goapp deploy`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use **dev_appserver.py**, that worked without issue! I was using **goapp serve** because that was the command that appeared in the tutorial when I created the App Engine.

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer to provide better visibility to future visitors to the question. I've left the other answer unedited because I think it might be relevant in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed on a [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963467/google-app-engine-goapp-deploy-works-but-serve-fails-whats-going-on#comment88926738_50963467) the solution was using [`dev_appserver.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server), instead of `goapp serve`.

`goapp` is the old tool to handle GAE tasks. Now it's recommended to use `dev_appserver.py` for the local development, and [`gcloud app`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/) commands for tasks in the cloud (e.g. `gcloud app deploy` instead of `goapp deploy`).

Note that `goapp` is not deprecated, but `dev_appserver.py` provides more flexibility on local dev, while `gcloud app` uses the properly documented and quite useful [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/) (unlike the older tools), making debugging a lot easier in case something goes wrong with your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine, if you need to get a context, you should probably use [`google.golang.org/appengine.NewContext()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#NewContext) for a context during an HTTP request, or [`google.golang.org/appengine.BackgroundContext()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#BackgroundContext) if it's outside a request. Both return `context.Context`, which is the same that you would get by creating a context through the `context` package, but with a context prepared to be used within GAE.

This does not tell you why the imports are not working (other than `goapp` looks to be using 1.6), but will just work around the issue avoiding you to import any `context` package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately in my case this wasn't relevant because I am not using context directly, so it must have been connected to one of the imports, all of which were either standard or offered by Google.